# Firebase taking long time to write document and freezing app

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to to write an array to a document on Firebase as the code below describes. However when that array contains 100 items (only names as strings, so no issue with quantity of data) it freezes the app for another minute and in the console I get the message

> Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
>    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

The internet connection is fine though. The issue also happens on a smaller array of only 20 items but isn't so pronounced.

What am I doing wrong that is causing the app to take such a long time to write to Firebase?

```
func saveDocOnline() {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("Collection 1").document("Document 1").setData([
        "Array" : loadItems()
    ]) { (error) in
        if let e = error {
            print("Error saving: \(e)")
        } else {
            print("Successfully Saved Online")
        }
    }
}

func loadItems() -> [String] {
    var itemTitle: [String] = []

    itemTitle = ["Generic", "Generic Bars", "Generic Restaurants" ... "Halloween", "Jazz", "Xmas", "Acid Jazz"]

    return itemTitle

}
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your exact code from the question into an app using a list of 1,000 words that I assigned to itemTitle. The code ran in less than 1 second. I then put your code into a tight loop and ran it 100 times. It works perfectly. That tells me the issue lies outside of that section of code. Are you perhaps using a DispatchGroup somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Very weird. Not 100% sure what could be causing this. I tried loading similar sized data without issue, but I would try a few things.

1. There might be an issue by calling a function inside as an argument for `setData()`. Try initializing the contents of `loadData` with a `let data:[String:[String]] = loadData()` before the `setData line`. Then use `data` as the argument instead of `loadData()`. That will do two things, it will help with type inference if Firebase is having trouble for some reason, and limits the scope of the function if firebase doesn't like that.
2. (Edit: ignore this suggestion, just reread your post and I can see you tried this)Also experiment with smaller sized arrays and see if you can successfully write 50 items. If that works, go for 75, or if it doesn't try 25. Etc. There might be a limit to the number of items in an array you can put up in this scenario, but that would be a pretty weird limitation of firebase.
3. try not using the keyword array, I don't think this will affect it, but just to be safe.

All these solutions, if they work, would suggest some weirdness inside the firebase framework, but at least you can eliminate possibilities.